# .net assert display condition failed with

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, f#, assert

OK, i'm used to good old C assertions, when they fail they output the condition they failed on, and the line it was on. (implimented with the preprocessor).

Now I'm programming in F# (a .net language), got code full of assert. (trying to program defensivly). and my assets show a popup with the call stack. according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx) could also pass the assert a string to display when it fails. so i could make it pass a string copy of my condition. eg:

```
assert (x=true, "x=true")
```

but this violate the Duplication (avoiding) principal.

If I later decide to change what I want to assert. (maybe i realised i was asserting something to be false when i should have been asserting it to be true) then I have to change the code in two places, otherwise the message won't match what I'm actually checking. and if i forget things could be really confusing.

How is this normally dealt with?

Comment: Use `assert(x=true, "What that condition actually means")` instead!

Comment: Asserts should be banned. They generate different code paths in debug vs release, they break automated testing environments, and it keeps the assert writing developer from actually handling the issue or throwing an exception.

Comment: @Ritch Shouldn't asserts be used in a unit-test?

Comment: @RitchMelton : I suggest you do a little reading on the difference between preconditions and postconditions before making a statement like that.

Comment: @Alxandr - xUnit asserts are a different beast than framework asserts.

Comment: @ildjam - Why? I've dealt with the issue. I know the problems that asserts cause. They're the wrong tool for any job in .net.

Comment: What are framework asserts then?

Comment: @RitchMelton : They're the right tool for verifying preconditions regardless of platform or language. Again, I doubt you fully understand the domain in question here.

Comment: @Alxandr - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx

Comment: @ildjarn - So if the precondition is wrong at release time, what happens?

Comment: @RitchMelton : If the precondition is wrong at release time then the code has a bug regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown. Using exceptions to handle programming errors is lazy/sloppy/irresponsible. `assert` has it's place, and that's to inform the author of the code that she made a mistake, not to inform the user of the program that the author made a mistake.

Comment: @ildjarn - I'm intrigued by `assert` and would like to be open minded about its use. For example, I notice that the F# compile source makes extensive use of them. But I share many of @RitchMelton's concerns. Specifically, I tend to subscribe to the "fail fast" philosophy common in the .NET community. It seems that asserts, when they are hit but ignored in non-DEBUG mode, would allow a program to gradually become unstable and make it hard for a user to submit a reproducible bug report. Instead of a finite number of isolated failure points, they seem to open up infinite permutations!

Comment: @Stephen : I was taking for granted that the code would actually be _tested_ (in DEBUG); if no testing is taking place, then `assert` won't be useful, but then we're back to lazy/sloppy/irresponsible anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Echoing what Tomas said, you can use quotations to avoid duplication. But instead of `ToLinqExpression -> ToString`, which apparently produces C# source code, you can use my library [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/) which produces F# source code strings. Combine this with an implementation suitable for production code (i.e. defining `Assert` inline with a non-`DEBUG` compilation symbol branch emitting only the no-op `()` means uses of `Assert` will be completely removed in non-`DEBUG` builds with optimizations turned on):

```
let inline Assert (q:Expr<bool>) =
    #if DEBUG
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(q.Eval(), q.Decompile())
    #else
        ()
    #endif
```

then the assertion expression `Assert <@ (22 + 2) / 2 = ("assert" |> String.length) @>` produces the following popup dialog by default (I think you can configure `System.Diagnostics.Debug` behavior):

[image]

Where in comparison `q.ToLinqExpression().ToString()` produces `(((22 + 2) / 2) == op_PipeRight("assert", ToFSharpFunc(str => Length(str))))`.

In fact, Unquote was designed specifically for the purpose of producing helpful unit test assertion failure messages, and can easily be adapted to debug assertions producing step-by-step failure messages:

```
let inline Assert (q:Expr<bool>) =
    #if DEBUG
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(q.Eval(), q.ReduceFully() |> List.map (fun q -> q.Decompile()) |> String.concat System.Environment.NewLine)
    #else
        ()
    #endif
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice - using unqote definitely makes the assert messages a lot better!

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what asserts are you asking about, there is no way to automatically get a textual representation of the condition that failed. The best option is to provide the information explicitly by using overload that takes a message:

```
Debug.Assert(a = 10, "A should be 10")
```

If you don't need to worry about the performance of `Assert`, then you can use F# quotations. They represent the code that was written and can be both evaluated (to test the assert) and formatted as strings:

```
#r @"C:\Programs\Development\PowerPack-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll"
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation

/// Assert that tests whether a quoted condition is true and throws
/// an exception containing a string representation of the code
let Assert (q:Expr<bool>) = 
  if not(q.Eval()) then failwithf "Assertion failed: %O" (q.ToLinqExpression())

let test() = 
  let a = 10
  Assert <@ a = 11 @>
```

Calling the `test` function will give you the message below. The call `ToLinqExpression` gives you a LINQ `Expression` object, which implements a nicer `ToString` operation than F# quotations:

> System.Exception: Assertion failed: (10 == 11)

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely different in C vs F#.  The C code must leave enough breadcrumbs to make the assertion message meaningful enough to help you find out where in the code your assertion failed.

That's a non-issue in managed code.  You get a stack trace, no need for the string.